Produce new record when specific combination of values detected
I am writing a CASE Expression and I need it to produce a new record if both variables are met.
I am essentially writing:
select unique_ID,
case when Columna > '0' then '18'
when Columnb > '0' then '06' else 'ee' end as Line_Code
from SampleTable

It produces the intended results:
UniqueID   Line_Code
12345          18
54321          06

The problem I am having is that I need another record produced if both line codes are > 0 to equal 18 and 06.
What I need is:
Unique_ID    Line_Code
12345           18
54321           06
54321           18

In the above statement both ColumnA and ColumnB have a value > 0.
Thank you

FYI case is an expression not a statement.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

And show us a complete query, not just the case expression.

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result. As it is now, we don't know the input data (incl ColumnA and ColumnB.) We're not playing SQL Jeopardy.

Just a guess, but if feels like a CROSS APPLY may help here.
Example
Declare @YourTable Table ([ColumnA] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('15')
,('0')
 
Select A.ColumnA 
      ,B.Line_Code
 from  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (case when ColumnA>'0' then '18' end ) 
                     ,(case when ColumnB>'0' then '06' else 'ee' end ) 
             ) B(Line_Code)
 Where Line_Code is not null

Results
ColumnA Line_Code
15      18
15      06
0       ee


should the second case not be on ColumnB instead of ColumnA and where does NewVal comes from ?

@GuidoG Good catch.   Some poor copy/paste and post edits.   The key point/method was CROSS APPLY to create additional records.
